# How to fetch YouTube shorts view count and public videos view count using Youtube data/reporting APIs?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I wanted to fetch the youtube shorts views count and youtube public view count to check the monetization status of my youtube account.

- Normal views metrics in youtube API return views on all videos including unlisted ones. Could not find any filters for public views.
- Could not find anything for youtube shorts in the docs.

[image: This form youtube studio is what I am trying to recreate]
Screenshot of the similar data in youtube studio.

Is it possible to fetch these data?

Tried fetching the views on each video and identify shorts and public videos from it. But I couldn't find anything to differentiate between shorts and a normal video. Same for public /unlisted videos.

Answer (score 0):

> But I couldn't find anything to differentiate between shorts and a normal video. Same for public /unlisted videos.

To distinguish shorts and normal videos, use [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71194751) relying on a web-scraping approach of the YouTube UI.

Concerning distinguishing public and unlisted videos, use [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with [`part=statistics`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part) to retrieve the [`viewCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics.viewCount) field.