# How to implement the shorts feature in youtube using java library com.google.api.services.youtube?

Tags: java, youtube

I am trying to implement the shorts feature in Java using the client library com.google.api.services.youtube. But I don't find any shorts related files in this java doc in this [link](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.apis/google-api-services-youtube/latest/index.html). Is there a way to fetch shorts video using youtube api v3 ?

Comment: Shorts are just videos. For more info, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/71192605/8681.