# What is the difference in these classes of HTTP request objects?

Tags: vba, http, request

For making an HTTP request in VBA, I've seen five different object classes to use:

- **Microsoft.XMLHTTP** ([StackOverflow answer](https://www.StackOverflow.com/questions/52142757/vba-download-csv-from-a-link/#52175815), 2018)
- **MSXML2.XMLHTTP60** ([MyExcelGenius](https://www.MyExcelGenius.com/getting-data-from-a-website-in-json-format-using-vba/), 2020)
- **MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0** ([ChatGPT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77120360/why-does-this-http-head-request-not-work-in-excel-vba), 2023)
- **MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0** ([MS documentation for `IXMLHTTPRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms759148(v=vs.85)), 2016, no longer being updated)
- **WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1** ([MS documentation for `WinHttpRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest), 2022 and [ChatGPT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77120360/why-does-this-http-head-request-not-work-in-excel-vba), 2023)

Is any one of these classes just as good as any of the others, or are there pros and cons? Is there another class not listed here that is better?

---

---

Edit (explaining correction of original post; can be safely ignored):

My original post of this question also showed differences in the way the object is created:

- `dim ... as <object class>`, then `set ... = new <object class>`
- `dim ... as object`, then `set ... = CreateObject(<object class>)`
- `dim ... as object`, then `set ... = new ActiveXObject(<object class>)`

and two different requisite libraries:

- Microsoft XML, v6.0
- Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1

After posting that, I found out that:

- `new ActiveXObject()` is valid in jScript, but in VBA needs to be replaced with either of the other two techniques.
- The difference between using [new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement) and [CreateObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createobject-function) is discussed in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170070/what-are-the-differences-between-using-the-new-keyword-and-calling-createobject).
- The library references are required with `new` and optional with `CreateObject()`.

Comment: So, you can use MSXML or WinHTTP, that are standard windows ways to do it. No other standard windows ways. Yet, you can install some third parties and use them.
Pros of MSXML, as name suggest it works well with XML. But it can be used for any text/json. WinHTTP is good for any other things you might want. But for text, json, xml, html, MSXML is more than enough.

Comment: I used to use your ways #1, 2 and 3 (mostly 1 or 2). Probably all good and all work.

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605613/differences-between-xmlhttp-and-serverxmlhttp

Comment: @TimWilliams - Wow, that's some detailed discussion of the differences between two of them (actually, between one and another with a name similar to one of the others). Now it would be great to have that for the other three.